# How to dynamically modify certain edge weights in an EdgePropertyMap

Tags: graph-tool

I was wondering what the most efficient way would be to dynamically modify the weight of a selection of edges in a graph. Can I do this in a temporary way without actually modifying the propertymap ? I can see the use of filters in the documentation, but fail to see how to change weights specifically. Underlying motive: I want to lower edge weights in certain geographical zones in order to "guide" a shortest path through a corridor.

Comment: I know you want an "efficient" method, but is simply copying the entire edge property map really so expensive for you?  How many edges are in your graph?

Comment: It would be an entire country like say the Netherlands, and I would need to do this for thousands of devices in a big data infrastructure. If the overhead would stay under let's say 100ms, that would be ok with me.

Comment: Another option I'm thinking of, but I don't know if that's possible with graph-tool: to use A* search where I change the heuristic during the path search. In other words, I would first like to pull my search towards a first waypoint, when that's almost reached, I'd like to pull it towards the second waypoint, etc. until I reach the destination.